# D3 Map not showing up in browser on local server

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I'm working on a D3 map that shows the provinces of China. I've tried a mix of several different tutorials, but I have been unsuccessful in making the map appear in browser, which uses the python local server.

I can see that the information of the map has been correctly enter into the g element, and that the GeoJSON file does include 32 provinces. I must be doing something wrong displaying it then?

Please see here for my code: https://github.com/claiye/map/blob/master/index.html
It's quite messy because I've tried several different tutorials that don't work for what I am aiming for.

Please point out what stupid mistake I must be making. Your help is most kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you check console log and paste the error here?

Comment: @srkushwaha There is no error in the console log at all. :(

Comment: And you mentioned you are using localserver. Are you referring to localhost i.e. 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @srkushwaha Yup! Using the Python local server thing... There is definitely no cross reference issue as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that the path created was not within the svg and g tag. Please check my two comments. I have verified below code is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Map Testing</title>
<style>
    .province{
        fill:#ccc;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var width = 960; 
        height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height",height);

    // Removed the slash before provinces.geojson
    d3.json("provinces.geojson", function(error, provinces) {
        if (error) return console.error(error);

        svg.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(provinces.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("class","province")
            .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator().center([0,5]).scale(200).rotate([-180,0]))); // Added center and rotate here
});
</script>
</body>
<html
```

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO SO SO SO SO MUCH!!

Comment: Please mark it as "Answer", so that if somebody else faces same issue, he/she can use the solution.